# Callback Functions(like afterMove) are not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

The following is a code taken form *Owl Carousel's* [own site](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/owlStatus.html). I don't know why the **callback functions**(here *afterMove*) are not called! Could anybody get the *afterMove* function called? For me it's not just *afterMove*, but none of the callbacks works!

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Owl Carousel -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/vendors/owl-carousel-2/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">

  <!-- Owl Default Theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/vendors/owl-carousel-2/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    #owl-demo .item {
        background: #3fbf79;
        padding: 30px 0px;
        margin: 10px;
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h1>0</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>5</h1></div>
    <div class="item"><h1>6</h1></div>
  </div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<script src="js/vendors/owl-carousel-2/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  var owl = $("#owl-demo");
  owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    afterMove : afterMove
  });

  function afterMove(){
    alert("Hey!");
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use new events with `.on()`, as per mentioned in its [docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html), as:

```
var owl = $("#owl-demo");
owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation : true
});
//register `change` event
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    alert("changed");
});
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbb9zhfb/)

Comment: Replacing my script with yours causes the alert dialog to be popped **twice**!